# How can I make a multilingual static website?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a begginer but I have my personal blog made entirely in html and I want to display multiple languages.
I've searched on how to do it but what they tea how to make the machine translate it, but I want to translate them manually so it doesn't feel odd. How could I do that?

I thought on placing the translated documents in separate folders (like spanish in es folder for example) but I don't know how could I place the link to the translated page. For example, when in an english (default language) post, change to the translated post instead of the spanish index.

Comment: Browsers can auto translate simple pages no problem.

Comment: @takendarkk — Human translation is almost always better.

Comment: No shit? Had no idea! I'll read up on that.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a sub-domain (`http://us-en.my-blog.com`) or top-level sub-directory (`http://my-blog.com/us-en`). Under the first approach, you simply make your links relative (`/my-other-page.html`). Then your links will always take you to pages under the same language translation.

So, for instance, if you are on the page `http://us-en.my-blog.com/` and click the link with the relative address `/about.html`, then the browser will navigate to `http://us-en.my-blog.com/about.html`

If, on the other hand, you go with a top-level sub-directory, then you will be required to include the language in the url (`/us-en/my-other-page.html`).

So, for instance, if you are on the page `http://my-blog.com/us-en` and click the link with the relative address `/us-en/about.html`, then the browser will navigate to `http://my-blog.com/us-en/about.html`. Be careful not to forget the `/us-en` prefix in your relative urls with this approach.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score -2):

> I thought on placing the translated documents in separate folders (like spanish in es folder for example)

Yes. That's all there is to it.

> but I don't know how could I place the link to the translated page.

`<a href="/es/foo">Spanish (<span lang="es">Española</span>)</a>` at its most basic.

`<a href="/es/foo" rel="alternate" hreflang="es">Spanish (<span lang="es">Española</span>)</a>` would be better.